# Run two commands in a row after an if statement in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Why does the following Clojure program throw a NullPointerException?

```
user=> (defn x []  
       "Do two things if the expression is true."
       (if true ((println "first expr") (println "second expr")) false))

user=> (x)
first expr
java.lang.NullPointerException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
second expr
```

This is a simplified version of my actual use case, where I want to execute maybe three statements (pull values from the DB) before returning a map - `{:status 200, :body "Hello World"}`  inside of the branch.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nullpointer in clojure when running doseq with multiple expressions in the body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530555/nullpointer-in-clojure-when-running-doseq-with-multiple-expressions-in-the-body)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is trying to treat the result of the first println as a function to call on the second println function.

You need a [`do`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/do).

```
(defn x []  
   "Do two things if the expression is true."
   (if true (do (println "first expr") (println "second expr")) false))

(x)
```

The `do` special form (progn in CL, begin in Scheme) executes each of its arguments in sequence and returns the result of the last one.

Comment: Yes, generally. A few forms might imply it (Scheme `cond` implies it, for instance, but I don't think Clojure's version does since its arguments aren't in lists). `((foo ...) (bar ...))` _generally_ implies taking the result of foo and using it as a function to call the rest of the arguments.

Comment: So does this mean that `do` will execute the statements sequentially? (it'll assume they have side effects)?

Comment: `do` will indeed execute its statements sequentially.

Answer (score 11):

If `nil` is ok as a return value in the else case, consider using `when` which has an implicit `do` block:

```
(defn x []  
  "Do two things if the expression is true."
  (when true
    (println "first expr") 
    (println "second expr")))
```

Answer (score 7):

Not that it matters in your particular case, but do know the difference between `(do ...)` which will load each form in its own classloader, and an empty let form `(let [] ...)` which evaluates the whole form in a single classloader.

Comment: What is the practical difference between loading each form in its own classloader vs otherwise? Maybe I don't understand the implications of classloader.

Comment: One example, you are writing a macro that defines a custom deftype and multiple classes. As an optimization, you would like to use the same classloader so that less classloader instances are created.